# JQuery / Javascript count data-(sort) values

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

Having a small thing here.
I have a table with bookings

```
<tr class="booking">
    <td>00234</td>
    <td onclick="window.location=('https://www.exmple.com/booking/view=777');" data-sort="64.99" class="price">
    €64,99
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I would like JQuery to iterate through all td.price fields and obtain the **data-sort""** value

I have tried the following:

```
var amount = 0;

$("#booking_table > tbody > > tr > td > data['data-sort']").each(function () {
    amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

But this is not working. (logically because I don't know how to approach the data-sort value. But there should be a way.

**Answer by Martin**

```
var amount = 0;

$("#booking_table > tbody > tr > .price[data-sort]").each(function () {
    amount += parseFloat($(this).data('sort'));
});
```

Comment: `data['data-sort']` is looking for an element `<data data-sort="XXX">` and the `> >` in a selector is wrong. I think you instead want `#booking_table > tbody > tr > td[data-sort]` although we can't say for certain without seeing a more complete example of your HTML. In addition, `td` elements don't have a `val()`. Try `amount += $(this).data('sort');` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only because you have a slight problem in your selector.

The selector you were using isn't correct:

```
#booking_table > tbody > > tr > td > data['data-sort']
```

You instead want:

```
#booking_table > tbody > tr > td[data-sort]
```

```js
var amount = 0;

$("#booking_table > tbody > tr > td[data-sort]").each(function() {
    amount += $(this).data('sort');
});

console.log(amount)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="booking_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="booking">
        <td>00234</td>
        <td onclick="window.location=('https://www.exmple.com/booking/view=777');" data-sort="64.99" class="price">
        €64,99
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you! The only thing still missing was parseFloat(), and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, as i cannot know your html selector, can be

```
$('#booking_table > tr.booking > td[data-sort]').each(function () {
   amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `td` elements don't have a `value`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in fact i write 'as i cannot know your html selector,' and the structure... the point is clarify the selector with data-...

Maybe can be

$('#booking_table > tr.booking > td[data-sort] > input').each(function () {
   amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
});

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can easly use  `$("#booking_table td[data-sort]").each(function() { ...` and make calculation ,

beacause in your case you're using `>` means  direct children of a parent .

```js
$(function() {
  let amount = 0;
  $("#booking_table td[data-sort]").each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).data('sort'));
    amount += parseFloat($(this).data('sort'));
  });
 alert("amount ="+  amount); 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="booking_table" border="1px solid ">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="booking">
      <td>00234</td>
      <td onclick="window.location=('https://www.exmple.com/booking/view=777');" data-sort="64.99" class="price">
        €64,99
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="booking">
      <td>00235</td>
      <td onclick="window.location=('https://www.exmple.com/booking/view=777');" data-sort="23.99" class="price">
        €23,99
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="booking">
      <td>00236</td>
      <td onclick="window.location=('https://www.exmple.com/booking/view=777');" data-sort="76.99" class="price">
        €76,99
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```